# Having Trouble Adding Pagination In Class Views ( get_queryset )

Tags: django, class, view, paginator

I'm trying to build a product category with pagination using class view (get_queryset). I followed a tutorial that did not actually cover this part that has get_queryset. I find it easier without get_queryset.

Below is the class base views (views.py)

```
class CatListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'category.html'
    context_object_name = 'catlist'
    paginate_by 12

    def get_queryset(self):
        content = {
            'cat': self.kwargs['category'],
            'posts': Post.objects.filter(category__name=self.kwargs['category']).filter(status='published')
        }
        return content
```

Template.html

```
 <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    {% if is_paginated %}
    <ul class="pagination">

      {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      <li class="page-item" style="color:#000;">
        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{page_obj.previous_page_number}}" style="color:#000; background:#98FB98;"
          >Previous</a>
      </li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="page-item disabled" style="color:#000;">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" style="background:#E5E4E2;">Previous</a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}

      {% for i in paginator.page_range %} 
      {% if page_obj.number == i %}

          <li class="page-item"  style="color:#000;">
              <a class="page-link active" style="background:#FF5E0E; color:#fff;">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% else %}
          <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
          </li>
      {% endif %} 
      {% endfor %} 
      
      {% if page_obj.has_next %}

          <li class="page-item" style="color:#000;">
          <a href="?page={{page_obj.next_page_number}}" class="page-link" style="color:#000; background:#98FB98;"
              >Next</a>
          </li>
      {% else %}
          <li class="page-item disabled"  style="color:#000;">
          <a class="page-link" style="background:#E5E4E2;">Next</a>
          </li>
      {% endif %}

    </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </nav>
```

It shows this error:

```
TypeError at /insu/category/django/
unhashable type: 'slice'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/insu/category/django/
Django Version: 4.1.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
unhashable type: 'slice'
Exception Location: C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Urocza-Bog-Limited\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py, line 80, in page
Raised during:  industrial_supply.views.CatListView
Python Executable:  C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Urocza-Bog-Limited\venv\scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Urocza-Bog-Limited\\src',
 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Urocza-Bog-Limited\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Urocza-Bog-Limited\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 08 Nov 2022 00:42:49 +0000
```

Kindly help me to implement paginator.

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: I posted the error above

Comment: Theres some missing. We can't see what file and line the error was raised in.

Answer (score 0):

`paginate_by 12` should be `paginate_by = 12`

Another thing to look at is using get_queryset to return only a queryset rather than a dict.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(category__name=self.kwargs['category']).filter(status='published')
```

Kwargs get added to the view context automatically. If you need to access a kwarg like 'category' in the template you can simply use.

```
{{view.kwargs.category}}
```

Comment: I corrected it, it's still the same. Thank you

Comment: As an example, could you please help me combine the cat and post to return post only? rather than a dict with posts and cat.. Thanks a lot

Comment: examples provided.

Comment: I will put this to work and give a feedback soon. Thank you so much

Comment: Good day Sir. I have made some beautiful progress with your help. (1). Using return Post.objects.filter(category__name=self.kwargs['category']).filter(status='published') helped me with the paginator. It worked really fine (2). Using {{view.kwargs.category}} allowed me to access the product category. However, when the product displays to the last page, the whole pagination disappears. I will take look at the Html part. THANK YOU SO MUCH. YOU HAVE BEEN SO HELPFUL. GOD BLESS MIGHTILY.

Comment: The HTM part is correct as well. It was because I used {% if is_paginated %}. Thank you so much once again. Please enjoy your day. I'm full of joy